# DRF CreateModelMixin with additional fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using GenericAPIView with the CreateModelMixin to create a model instance. I need my serializer to add additional fields that aren't defined by the user. My `Serializer.create` method is already set up for this, but I don't know how to pass fields through to the `CreateModelMixin.create` method. Here's a minimal version of what I have:

```py
class Foo(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return FooSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        return self.create(
            request, requester=request.user  # Additional field
        )
```

This doesn't work - the `requester` field isn't passed to `FooSerializer.save`, so `FooSerializer` throws an error when it attempts to access `requester` in `FooSerializer.create`. Before, I was using APIView and calling the serializer directly, so I could simply:

```py
serializer = FooSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    foo = serializer.save(requester=request.user)
```

Is there any way to achieve this with the `GenericAPIView`? I want to embrace DRF's DRY-ness and avoid calling serializers in every endpoint method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding `create` method you can override `perform_create`. Also you may need to define `post` method:

```
class Foo(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return FooSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(requester=self.request.user)
```